# R (RShiny) equivalent of layer_data function for other types of plots

Tags: r, plot, datatable, shiny, yaxis

I am building an RShiny-app where I am creating a plot based on a data table which I can edit and another data table which I cannot. I eventually want to save all data points on the plot in a data table which I can display and export.

I have seen many ways to do this using ggplot (ie layer_data, ggplot_build), but no efficient ways when just using plot and lines. My plots will be getting quite complicated so it would be really helpful to find an easy way to do this rather than hardcoding everything in.

A very simple example of my code is below (Note: plots will be getting much more complicated than this. They will be line graphs, but I will just need the y values at each x value marked with a number on the x axis):

```
x <- data.frame('col_1' = c(1,2,3,4,5), 'col_2' = c(4,5,6,7,8))
y <- data.frame('col_1' = c(5,4,3,6,7), 'col_2' = c(1,2,3,4,5))

#import necessary libraries
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(rhandsontable)

#ui
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                titlePanel("Test"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(

                    #display data
                    rHandsontableOutput('contents'),
                    #update plot button
                    actionButton("go", "Plot Update"),
                    width=4

                  ),
                mainPanel(

                  tabsetPanel(
                    #plot
                    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot_1")) )
                ))
)




#server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #data table
  output$table_b <- renderTable(x)

  indat <- reactiveValues(data=y)


  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$contents))
      indat$data <- hot_to_r(input$contents)

  })

  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(indat$data)
  })

  #save updated data
  test <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    live_data = hot_to_r(input$contents)
    return(live_data)
  })


  #plot
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({

    plot(x[,1],x[,2],col='red',type = 'l')
    lines(test()[,1],x[,2], col='black', type='l')


    # need a way to grab data from plot a create a table
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```